# Запятые в сложносочиненных предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Растолкуйте, пожалуйста, в каких случаях ставится запятая перед союзом И в сложносочиненных предложениях. Изменились ли за полвека эти правила? Спасибо. 
09.01.2014 г. Олег Крюк, пенсионер.

Answer (score 3):

Да нет, уважаемый Олег, никаких изменений нет, если только уточнили и расшифровали для тех, кто не понимает основного смысла. Можете сравнить сами:
 Вот современное: 
http://licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_1_2

вот Розенталь:http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm

1. Простые предложения, входящие в состав сложносочинённого предложения, отделяются друг от друга запятыми:
   Окна во всех корпусах были ярко освещены, и оттого на громадном дворе казалось оченьтемно (Чехов)
2. Запятая перед одиночными соединительными и разделительными союзами – и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо – не ставится в следующих случаях:

а) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют общий второстепенный член:
Вскоре после восхода набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (Пушкин) (общий второстепенный член – обстоятельство времени вскоре после восхода, ср.: Вскоре после восхода набежала туча; Вскоре после восхода брызнул короткий дождь);

б) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют общее придаточное предложение:
Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату (Л. Толстой) (придаточное времени когда я вернулся в свою комнату является общим для обеих частей сложносочинённого предложения, ср.: Уже совсем рассвело, когда я вернулся в свою комнату; Народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату);

в) простые предложения сложносочинённого предложения вместе поясняют общее для них третье предложение, предшествующее им и связанное с ними бессоюзной связью:
Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль (Куприн) (части сложносочинённого предложения: Тело было слабо; В глазах ощущалась тупая боль – поясняют смысл общего для них первого простого предложения, связанного с ними бессоюзно: Он чувствовал себя нехорошо);

г) простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют общее вводное слово, вводное словосочетание или предложение:
По словам охотников, зверь в этих лесах вывелся и птица исчезла (источник сообщения – по словам охотников – один и тот же для всего высказывания, ср.: По словам охотников, зверь в этих лесах вывелся; По словам охотников, птица исчезла);

д) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят вопросительные предложения:
Вы придёте ко мне или я должен зайти к вам?

е) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят побудительные предложения:
Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! (Фурманов);

ж) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят восклицательные предложения:
Как он смешон и как глупы его выходки!

з) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят односоставные неопределенно-личные предложения, если мыслится один и тот же производитель действия:
Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад (Л. Толстой);

и) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят безличные предложения, имеющие синонимические слова в сказуемых:
Необходимо рассмотреть авторские заявки и надо срочно составить по ним заключения (синонимы: необходимо, надо).
Но при отсутствии синонимических слов запятая между двумя безличными предложениями перед союзом и ставится:
Между тем совсем рассвело, и надо было опять выходить в море (Катаев);

к) в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят назывные (номинативные) предложения:
Мороз и солнце... (Пушкин).

Comment: Я хотела спросить, действует ли сейчас исключение, связанное с союзом ИЛИ:Дядя в вас влюблён,   или нет? Можешь шагу прибавить,  или силёнок нет? Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя? - здесь общая вопросительная интонация, но при наличии союза ИЛИ в виде исключения запятая ставится.

Comment: По-моему, это не исключение, а интонационная запятая - ставится факультативно, если прочитали с паузой, т.е. авторская. Интонация получается не общая, а одинаковая, как при присоединении. По сути это и есть присоединение, здесь другие знаки препинания. Синтаксическая омонимия.А с общей интонацией - "Дядя в вас влюблён или нет? "

Comment: При вопросительной интонации должна быть общая фраза восходящего тона - ее как-то трудно построить. Такое впечатление, что здесь две восходящие фразы. А правило такое мне встречалось в учебниках.

Comment: Но ведь там не сказано, что обязательна запятая перед ИЛИ7 Ты пойдёшь или нет? Хочешь ты этого или не хочешь? Ты идёшь или остаёшься? Можно прочитать и с паузой, и без неё.

Comment: В правилах говорится именно о запятой - это обычные справочники по пунктуации, до интонации им и дела никакого нет. Я просто пытаюсь объяснить их правило с помощью интонации.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не изменилось. Запятая в ССП перед союзом И ставится, кроме следующих случаев:

1) есть объединяющий элемент: общий второстепенный член, общее придаточное, общее вводное слово; 
2) части  ССП представляют собой два вопросительных, побудительных или восклицательных предложения;
3) части ССП представляют собой безличные предложения с синонимичными сказуемыми.