# Запятая между двумя вопросительными предложениями

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

> Включать свет(,) или можно без него?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Нужна ли запятая перед союзом ИЛИ в сложносочиненном предложении с вопросительной интонацией?**  На этот вопрос нужно отвечать очень осмотрительно.  Если вы не хотите, чтобы вас «побили камнями», то надо сказать, что **запятая не нужна,** о чем говорится в правилах наших классиков

**Розенталь**: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?  Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня? Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?

**Лопатин:** http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:

если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация: Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация;

2. С другой стороны, примеры, приведенные у Розенталя и Лопатина, **очень простые.**  Там действительно нет никакого желания ставить запятые – интонация явно объединяет эти предложения, поэтому они произносятся в одну фразу, пауза не обозначена.
3. Но в жизни все сложнее, бывают и другие предложения, **более  распространенные, да еще  с собственными знаками.**  А иногда автор текста **хочет обозначить паузу** для решения своей художественной задачи. В конце концов, части предложения объединяет вопросительная интонация, но вот союз ИЛИ – разделительный!  Тенденции в некотором смысле противоположные.
4. **Но попробуйте сказать об этом.** Если вы спросите тихо и вежливо, как ученик у учителя, то ничего, обойдется. Вам просто объяснят, что так делать не нужно,  **так как правила исключений не допускают.** Если же будете говорить громче да еще настаивать, то я вам не позавидую: на вас обрушатся такие эмоции, такие вы услышите слова, что не дай бог. Вас будут обличать и ставить на место ревнители формализма и однозначности.

Вот примеры
http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1751684-zapjataja-pri-vstreche-li-l-ili-ili-soglasny-li-vy-so-slovarjom.html

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/Запятые-в-сложносочиненных-предложениях/28922#comment28924_28922](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/28922#comment28924_28922)

Здесь обсуждение ИЛИ в комментариях.

5. Поэтому я поступлю очень осторожно. **Из Нацкорпуса я приведу примеры с запятой** –  это  (1) распространенные предложения, части которых сложно объединить вопросительной интонацией; (2) разговорный стиль общения на форумах.

**Художественная литература**

Маша вам еще понадобится, или можно считать, что показания с нее сняты?

Так мы пьем, или мне уехать? [Андрей Клепаков, 2016]

Пора отсюда выбираться, или надо подождать, пока эта она прекратит урчать? [Марианна Баконина,  2000]

**Разговорный стиль:**

― А мы всегда в Сети ненастоящие, или можно избежать сознательного построения образа?

И еще, мне теперь в другие темки писать, или можно здесь остаться?

Клей-карандаш более-менее сойдет, или надо искать особый тип?

**Другие способы обозначить паузу (многоточие, тире, парцелляция):**

― Так это дальний родственник… или все же сын? [Дина Рубина  (2014)]

― Унести на себе можно ― или надо с машиной подъезжать? [Андрей Лазарчук, 1996]

― Что, ты легла уже? Или все еще у экрана?  [С. В. Соловьев, 2012]

**6.  А теперь ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС.**

Это ССП,  оба предложения в составе ССП вопросительные, безличные, одиночный союз ИЛИ. Если решать задачу по правилам, то запятая не нужна. Интонационно эти простые предложения объединить несложно: ***Включать свет или можно без негО?***  Ударение падает на конец фразы, пауза не обозначается.

Если вы решаете этот вопрос для себя, ничем не рискуете и ни перед кем не отвечаете, то можно допустить авторский вариант с паузой, запятой и дополнительным ударением на первой части:  ***ВключАть свет,  или можно без негО?***

7. **В заключение у меня будет вопрос** к  любителям формальной однозначности в решениях.  А могу ли я в некоторых случаях считать союз ИЛИ **присоединительным, а не пояснительным?** Тогда правило на такой союз **не распространяется,** соответственно, я могу ставить или не ставить  запятую по своему усмотрению.